# How to add values into a list in case of collision in java 8?

Tags: java-8

I am new to Java 8, I want to do something like this in java 8:

```
Map<String, List<Tuple>> userTupleMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Tuple tuple : tupleList) {
    userTupleMap.get(tuple.get("user_id",String.class)).add(tuple);
}
```

I want to create a list of tuples which have same "user_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` of Stream API

```
Map<String, List<Tuple>> userTupleMap = tupleList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tuple -> tuple.get("user_id",String.class)));
```

Comment: One more thing, What if I want to create Map<String, Map<string, List<Tuple>>> a hint would be enough.

Comment: @AdityaVerma What is the inner map key ? You can use nested groupingBy then.

Comment: Lets say its project_id or something

Comment: You can do like `Collectors.groupingBy(..., Collectors.groupingBy(...))`